# Uncaught TypeError: item.removeAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando fazer uma função que adicione um atributo à tags buttons quando a tela do dispositivo possui um certo tamanho. Porém, recebo sempre o erro de typeError. Criei um for in para percorrer a nodelist selecionada pelo QuerySelectorAll, mas aparentemente eu não estou conseguindo atingir os elementos individualmente para executar este método nele

```js
function sizeScreen() {
    var altura = window.innerHeight
    || document.documentElement.clientHeight
    || document.body.clientHeight;

    const titleButton = document.querySelectorAll(".title")

    if (altura <= 768) {
        for (var item in titleButton) {
            item.removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        };
        }
    else {
        titleButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    };

sizeScreen();
```

```html
div class="line-title"></div>
                <li><button class="title" type="button" disabled> Apple Store</button></li>
                <div class="list-items">
                    <li>Encontre uma loja</li>
                    <li>Genius Bar</li>
                    <li>Today at Apple</li>
                    <li>Apple Camp</li>
                    <li>App Aple Store</li>
                    <li>Financiamento</li>
                    <li>Programa de Reciclagem da <br> Apple</li>
                    <li>Status do seu pedido</li>
                    <li>Ajuda para comprar</li>
                </div>
            </ul>
            <div id="column2">
                <ul>
                    <div class="line-title"></div>
                    <li><button class="title" type="button" disabled>Para Empresas</button></li>
                    <div class="list-items">
                        <li>Apple e os negócios</li>
                        <li>Comprar para a sua empresa</li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <div class="line-title"></div>
                    <li><button class="title" type="button" disabled>Para a Educação</button></li>
                    <div class="list-items">
                        <li>Apple e a Educação</li>
                        <li>Comprar para a Educação Básica</li>
                        <li>Comprar para a faculdade</li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <div class="line-title"></div>
                    <li><button class="title" type="button" disabled>Para a Saúde</button></li>
                    <div class="list-items">
                        <li>Apple e a Saúde</li>
                        <li>Saúde no Apple Watch</li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

s.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a decifrar como resolver isso?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: item.removeAttribute() é uma função que recebe apenas 1 atrinbuto, que é o nome do atributo a ser removido. Se isso não resolve o problema recomendo utilizar console.log(item) para verificar se os elementos estão corretos

Comment: `for (let item in items)` passa o índice (um inteiro) para `item`. Já o loop `for (let item of items)` passa o elemento para `item`.

Answer (score -2):

use o `for(;;)` envés de `for( in )` desse jeito:

```
function sizeScreen(){
    var altura = window.innerHeight
    || document.documentElement.clientHeight
    || document.body.clientHeight;
    
    const titleButton = document.querySelectorAll(".title");
    
    if(altura <= 768){
        for(let i = 0; i < titleButton.length;i++){
            titleButton[i].removeAttribute("disabled","disabled");
        }
    }else {
        for(let i = 0; i < titleButton.length;i++){
            titleButton[i].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
        }
    }
}
sizeScreen();
```

eu também já tive esse mesmo problema e foi assim que eu resolvi espero ter te ajudado.

Comment: cometi um pequeno erro o metodo `removeAttribute()` leva apenas um atributo porém nos meus testes também funciona com 2 pois o segundo é ignorado pelo sistema